# Relative Layout GridView inside of ScrollView Android

Tags: android, gridview, scrollview

I've a feeling I am doing this totally incorrect but I know stack overflow loves an attempt. I am trying to make my whole view scrollable and the icons in my grid view will scroll with my whole view, right now just the icons scroll. I am unsure where to even start with this. I will attach my layout file onto this. I want it to look like below but be a full scrollable view right now only the icons at the bottom scroll.

[image: App View]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView>
<RelativeLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.curtisboylan.myapplication.SearchScreen"
    android:background="@color/grey2">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView9"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
        android:layout_width="400dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="185dp"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_height="60dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView7"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
        android:layout_width="400dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="115dp"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_height="60dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView5"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
        android:layout_width="400dp"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp" />

    <!-- DataPicker Text Label and button -->

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Time Displayed Here"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:id="@+id/txt_TextDateTime"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView5"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="17dp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Click To Change Date"
        android:id="@+id/btn_datePicker"
        android:background="@null"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView5"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_x="-10dp"
        android:layout_y="481dp"
        android:background="@drawable/topbar"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:text="Continue"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
        android:layout_height="190dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView9"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp">
    </GridView>

    <TextView
        android:text="What is your location?"
        android:layout_x="200dp"
        android:layout_y="366dp"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_marginLeft="48dp"
        android:layout_width="275dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/devices"
        android:id="@+id/imageView8"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="125dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/locicon1"
        android:id="@+id/imageView6"
        android:layout_width="22dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView9"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView8"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/imageView8"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:background="@drawable/locationicon2"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView6"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_marginBottom="9dp" />

    <Button
        android:text=""
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:layout_width="280dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:id="@+id/googleLocBtn"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/button3" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:hint="What is the device you wish to fix?"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView8"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView8"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/button3" />

    <!-- End -->

</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: use nestedscrollview instead of scrollview

Comment: As @JaydeepPatel NestedScrollView is more appropriate to use if you have one or more scrollable child. Check this : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/NestedScrollView.html

Comment: @Haresh Chhelana yes it has gridview and other views.

Answer (score 0):

Use `android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView` instead of `ScrollView`.

**Try this:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout  
        android:id="@+id/activity_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:background="@color/grey2">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView9"
            android:layout_below="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
            android:layout_width="400dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="185dp"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:layout_height="60dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView7"
            android:layout_below="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
            android:layout_width="400dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="115dp"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:layout_height="60dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView5"
            android:layout_below="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
            android:layout_width="400dp"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp" />

        <!-- DataPicker Text Label and button -->

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Time Displayed Here"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:id="@+id/txt_TextDateTime"
            android:textSize="30dp"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView5"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="17dp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Click To Change Date"
            android:id="@+id/btn_datePicker"
            android:background="@null"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView5"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_x="-10dp"
            android:layout_y="481dp"
            android:background="@drawable/topbar"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:text="Continue"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        <GridView
            android:id="@+id/gridView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:numColumns="auto_fit"
            android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
            android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
            android:layout_height="190dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imageView9"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp">
        </GridView>

        <TextView
            android:text="What is your location?"
            android:layout_x="200dp"
            android:layout_y="366dp"
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_marginLeft="48dp"
            android:layout_width="275dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/devices"
            android:id="@+id/imageView8"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="125dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/locicon1"
            android:id="@+id/imageView6"
            android:layout_width="22dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView9"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView8"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/imageView8"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:background="@drawable/locationicon2"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView6"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_marginBottom="9dp" />

        <Button
            android:text=""
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:layout_width="280dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:id="@+id/googleLocBtn"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/button3" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/editText2"
            android:hint="What is the device you wish to fix?"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView8"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView8"
            android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/button3" />

        <!-- End -->

    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: Tried that, all its doing now is crashing and giving "Exception raised during rendering: ScrollView can host only one direct child"

Comment: Yes, ScrollView can contain only one direct child. Did your tried using android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView?

Comment: Yeah thats the one thats giving me the issues.

Comment: In my answer, android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView has only one direct child(RelativeLayout). Please clean and build your project again and then try.